# docker-compose can't find the file

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I have created below  docker file and the intention is to run it in docker-compose.

```
FROM python:3.7.5-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN python -m pip install boto3
COPY test_cf_create_or_update.py .
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD [@]
```

Now after the build, when I run it I have expected outcome.

```
docker build -t test .
docker run -it --rm test  test_cf_create_or_update.py
```

However, If I do want to recreate same via docker-compose, it's saying

```
setup-application_1  | python3: can't open file '/usr/src/app/test_cf_create_or_update.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
localstack_setup-application_1 exited with code 2
```

Sample of docker-compose looks like below:

```
setup-application:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - /tmp/localstack/application:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=dummyaccess
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=dummysecret
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
    entrypoint: python3
    command: /usr/src/app/test_cf_create_or_update.py
    networks:
      - my_localstack_network
    depends_on:
      - localstack
```

Can anyone assist me in where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your work directory in your docker file is already usr/src/app. So by the time it your docker-compose file runs, you should already be in that directory and your command should just be test_cf_create_or_update.py. (Note that since you have a volume mapped to usr/src/app, the host directory (/tmp/localstack/application) should contain test_cf_create_or_update.py)

Comment: yes, you right my volume was the problem. I mapped to a different location. Thanks, that solves the problem.

Comment: I'd suggest deleting the `volumes:` setting so that you're actually running the code that's in the image, and not overwriting the `/usr/src/app` directory there with something else.  You also don't need to repeat `entrypoint:` and `command:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  (I'd probably combine these into a single `CMD` in the Dockerfile.)

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions :

Remove `volume` from `docker-compose` and

```
FROM python:3.7.5-slim
COPY test_cf_create_or_update.py .
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN python -m pip install boto3
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD [@]
```

Or keep `volume` in `docker-compose` and

```
FROM python:3.7.5-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN python -m pip install boto3
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD [@]
```

Make sure your `test_cf_create_or_update.py` is in `/tmp/localstack/application` folder.

Comment: I removed the volume from the docker compose.

Comment: @change198 ok, you can try first method then.